# Позиция картинки

Tags: css, css3

Как зафиксировать картинку по центру, а то при изменения размера окна браузера, картинка смещается [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот она смещается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка не изменяла свое расположение по вертикали, использовал:

```
position:relative;
bottom: 100px
```

Comment: Выложи сюда разметку и  стили...

Comment: Наработки свои скинь. Если я правильно понял и мы говорим за фон то пропиши     к фону background-size: cover; height: 100vh; при условии что контейнер на всю высоту уже. Если нет, то и контейнер делай на всю высоту

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так должно сработать, двигаем картинку трансформом на половину высоты вверх и на половину ширины влево, и выставляем `top: 50%;` и `left: 50%;`, при этом у элемента должен быть задано абсолютное позиционирование:

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img class="center" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=128">
```

---

Еще вариант с `calc(50% - XXXpx)`

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<img class="center" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=128">
```

---

И наверное самый лаконичный способ, только при помощи трансформов:

```css
.center {
  transform: translate(50vw, 50vh) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img class="center" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=128">
```

Comment: `calc` все таки лучше не использовать, зачем напрягать браузер лишними вычислениями?)

Comment: @DaemonHK он так и так это посчитает =)